# Sails.js redirect www to no www url

Tags: javascript, sails.js

Is there a way to redirect all incoming requests for something like `www.`example.com to example.com in Sails (removing www)? In xampp php server this was usually done with .htaccess. How do we go about it in Sails.js (node) server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sails.js uses express. Which means any middleware for express will work, such as

- https://github.com/edwardhotchkiss/subdomain

Here is the relivant documentation on the sails.js site.

- http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Middleware

Example using the subdomain module
config/http.js

```
module.exports.http = {
  middleware: {

    removeSubDomain: require('subdomain')({base: 'yourdomain.com'}),

    // Now configure the order/arrangement of our HTTP middleware
    order: [
      'startRequestTimer',
      'removeSubDomain',
      'cookieParser',
      'session',
      'bodyParser',
      'compress',
      'methodOverride',
      'poweredBy',
      '$custom',
      'router',
      'www',
      'favicon',
      '404',
      '500'
    ]
  }
}
```